# c# filter listview using textbox

Tags: c#, listview, filter, textbox

I have listview that is getting data from sql database .. I want to search by text entered in textbox and show the result after clicking a button and hide the records that doesn't match

here's my approach

plz help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Inventory_Manager_Pro
{
public partial class Modify : Form
{

    public SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=10.0.0.13;Initial Catalog=INVENTDB;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=farespila010A@;Encrypt=False");


    public Modify()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void populate()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();

        SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lapdev", cn);

        try
        {

            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(dr["fillingcode"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["username"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["branch"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["department"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["agency"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["computername"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["lapmodel"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["lapserial"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["assetnumber"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["os"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["winlicense"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["office"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["officelicense"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["hddsize"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["processor"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["ram"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["macadress"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["ipadress"].ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(it);

            }

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }

    private void Modify_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cn.Open();
            populate();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Application.ExitThread();
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
listView1.Items.Clear(); // clear list items before adding 
    listView1.Items.AddRange(Items.Where(i=>string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text)||i.Name.StartsWith(textBox1.Text))
        .Select(c => new ListViewItem(c.Name)).ToArray());

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

}
```

}

Comment: I can see exactly where your issue is.. but can you? Have you tried to solve this at all? Have you learnt any SQL further than `SELECT * FROM`? We can give you answers.. but they are answers that you should be able to investigate yourself. Sorry if that sounds harsh.

Comment: I have been searching for 2 days non stop .. please help if u can

Comment: "SELECT * FROM lapdev WHERE YourField='" + textBox1.Text + "'"

Comment: nice website with examples sql and other stuff check it out after - http://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp

Comment: terrybozzio thaks so much but can you show me where should i put that code in the code above

Comment: sorry to ask too many questions

Comment: in your command - your cm variable

Comment: you mean in the button click ?
if no plz direct me how to do it please

Comment: i`ve posted answer , the populate method and the button click  method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pupolate method do this:

```
    private void populate()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        SqlCommand cm;
        if(textBox1.Text == "")
           cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lapdev", cn);
        else
            cm = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM lapdev WHERE YourField='" + textBox1.Text + "'", cn);


        try
        {

            SqlDataReader dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {

                ListViewItem it = new ListViewItem(dr["fillingcode"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["username"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["branch"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["department"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["agency"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["computername"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["lapmodel"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["lapserial"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["assetnumber"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["os"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["winlicense"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["office"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["officelicense"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["hddsize"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["processor"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["ram"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["macadress"].ToString());
                it.SubItems.Add(dr["ipadress"].ToString());

                listView1.Items.Add(it);

            }

            dr.Close();
            dr.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
```

and in your button click event:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //listView1.Items.Clear(); // clear list items before adding 
         populate();
         //you type what you want in textbox then click button.
    }
```

you dont even need to call clear on button click because populate method already takes care of that.

Comment: new edit i forgot no need to call clear on button,populate method takes care of that.